# Smartphones resolution responsive

Tags: html, css

I have a website that looks like the one in the attached screenshot. I want it to always look like it, with no scrolling down.

The problem is when I check my website in iphone4, so I must scroll down for watching the circle images that are at the bottom. How can I make it looks like the screenshot even in smartphone with low resolution
[The Screenshot, from LG G6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWSxe.jpg)

Comment: To answer your below comment, with media query one might need to cover a lot of resolutions, yes, ...but if you post a minimal working code snippet, you might get some better answers. I hope you understand we can't suggest solutions to code related issues without the code, right?

Answer (score 0):

Use `@media only screen` found in CSS. [More info here](http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/)

Long story short, once the dimensions get to a certain size, switch your style to make the picture fit better on the screen. Typical usage looks like:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 768px) 
and (max-width : 1024px)  { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```

Comment: `min/max-device-width` has been deprecated

Comment: With this technique i need to configure almost all the smartphones resolution, i mean Galaxy6 resolution, iPhone 6 resolution, iPhone 6+ resolution etc...

Comment: Nothing, use `min/max-width`

Comment: @wps not necessarily.  Just choose the largest one out of those devices and style it to that. The other display's won't be perfect, but with a center alignment  it should still fill up most of the screen.